# Parent and Child sorting using Lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lambda

I'm currently working on a project and working some lambda expressions (basics). And I have this requirement that I need to display the data based on hierarchy (parent and child).

Current Class:

```
   public class Phones
    {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public int ChildOf { get; set; }

    }
```

Current Data

```
ID   Phone   ChildOf  
1    Samsung    0  
2    Apple     0  
3    GalaxyS3   1  
4    GalaxyS4   1  
5    5S         2  
6    iPhone 6+  2
```

I'm expecting a result of:
**Results**

```
**Samsung**  
GalaxyS3  
GalaxyS4  
**Apple**  
5S  
iPhone6+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the linq as below.

```
var result = phoneList.Where(x=>x.ChildOf!=0).GroupBy(x=>x.ChildOf).Select(g=> new {Key = phoneList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ChildOf==0 && x.ID ==g.Key).Phone,Value = g.Select(x => x.Phone)});
```

But mind you `phoneList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ChildOf==0)` this is happening just because you want the `Phone Name` for the grouping Key.

You can do the separate dictionary to get the values and use it. But if you have the parent ID then why use the name. You can use the parent ID whenever you required from the group key. IF you are to do this,

```
var result = phoneList.Where(x=>x.ChildOf!=0).GroupBy(x=>x.ChildOf).Select(g=> g.Key,g.ToList());
```

And when you need to show that on the UI Just replace the Key with the matching parent ID. That would reduce the lot of performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suffice:

```
var lookup = phoneData.Where(e => e.ChildOf == 0)
                                   .ToDictionary(id => id.Id, value => value.Phone);

var result = phoneData.Where(e => e.ChildOf > 0)
                      .GroupBy(e => lookup[e.ChildOf])
                      .Select(g => new { Parent = g.Key, Children = g.Select(x => x.Phone) });
```

Where `phoneData` is an enumerable of your raw data.